# Pig script doesn't work with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to use Hadoop and Apache Pig. I have a .txt file with some data and a script .pig file with my script :

```
student = LOAD '/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',')
   as (id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, phone:chararray, city:chararray);

student_order = ORDER student BY firstname ASC;

Dump student_order;
```

And this is my .txt file :

```
001,Rajiv,Reddy,21,9848022337,Hyderabad
002,siddarth,Battacharya,22,9848022338,Kolkata
003,Rajesh,Khanna,22,9848022339,Delhi
004,Preethi,Agarwal,21,9848022330,Pune
005,Trupthi,Mohanthy,23,9848022336,Bhuwaneshwar
006,Archana,Mishra,23,9848022335,Chennai
007,Komal,Nayak,24,9848022334,trivendram
008,Bharathi,Nambiayar,24,9848022333,Chennai
```

But, when I execute : **pig -x mapreduce data.pig**

```
17/07/25 17:04:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
17/07/25 17:04:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
17/07/25 17:04:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2017-07-25 17:04:59,399 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.17.0 (r1797386) compiled Jun 02 2017, 15:41:58
2017-07-25 17:04:59,399 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/srv-hadoop/pig_1500995099397.log
2017-07-25 17:04:59,749 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-07-25 17:04:59,930 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/srv-hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2017-07-25 17:05:00,062 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2017-07-25 17:05:00,066 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:54310
2017-07-25 17:05:00,470 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost:54311
2017-07-25 17:05:00,489 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Pig Script ID for the session: PIG-data.pig-2bb2e75c-41a7-42bf-926f-05354b881211
2017-07-25 17:05:00,489 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - ATS is disabled since yarn.timeline-service.enabled set to false
2017-07-25 17:05:01,230 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: ORDER_BY
2017-07-25 17:05:01,279 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2017-07-25 17:05:01,308 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NestedLimitOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2017-07-25 17:05:01,362 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Selected heap (PS Old Gen) of size 699400192 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489580128, usageThreshold = 489580128
2017-07-25 17:05:01,411 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2017-07-25 17:05:01,452 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.SecondaryKeyOptimizerMR - Using Secondary Key Optimization for MapReduce node scope-23
2017-07-25 17:05:01,462 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 3
2017-07-25 17:05:01,462 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 3
2017-07-25 17:05:01,515 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2017-07-25 17:05:01,516 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2017-07-25 17:05:01,548 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2017-07-25 17:05:01,552 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2017-07-25 17:05:01,552 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2017-07-25 17:05:01,555 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2017-07-25 17:05:01,558 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2017-07-25 17:05:01,570 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.submit.replication is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication
2017-07-25 17:05:01,891 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/srv-hadoop/pig/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp1676993497/tmp-1698368733/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar
2017-07-25 17:05:01,932 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/srv-hadoop/pig/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp1676993497/tmp885160047/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2017-07-25 17:05:01,975 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/srv-hadoop/pig/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp1676993497/tmp-1346471388/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2017-07-25 17:05:02,012 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/srv-hadoop/pig/lib/joda-time-2.9.3.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp1676993497/tmp32088650/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2017-07-25 17:05:02,023 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2017-07-25 17:05:02,031 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2017-07-25 17:05:02,031 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2017-07-25 17:05:02,031 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2017-07-25 17:05:02,093 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2017-07-25 17:05:02,095 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2017-07-25 17:05:02,095 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2017-07-25 17:05:02,104 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-07-25 17:05:02,113 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
2017-07-25 17:05:02,178 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2017-07-25 17:05:02,207 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage - Using PigTextInputFormat
2017-07-25 17:05:02,213 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Cleaning up the staging area file:/home/srv-hadoop/hadoop-2.6.2/tmp/mapred/staging/srv-hadoop1897657638/.staging/job_local1897657638_0001
2017-07-25 17:05:02,214 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:data.pig got an error while submitting 
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:301)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:280)
    ... 18 more
2017-07-25 17:05:02,597 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local1897657638_0001
2017-07-25 17:05:02,597 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases student
2017-07-25 17:05:02,597 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: student[1,10],student[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2017-07-25 17:05:02,600 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2017-07-25 17:05:07,608 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2017-07-25 17:05:07,608 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local1897657638_0001 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2017-07-25 17:05:07,609 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2017-07-25 17:05:07,619 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-07-25 17:05:07,620 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
2017-07-25 17:05:07,620 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2017-07-25 17:05:07,622 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.6.2   0.17.0  srv-hadoop  2017-07-25 17:05:01 2017-07-25 17:05:07 ORDER_BY

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1897657638_0001    student MAP_ONLY    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:301)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:280)
    ... 18 more


Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1897657638_0001    ->  null,
null    ->  null,
null


2017-07-25 17:05:07,622 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2017-07-25 17:05:07,624 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias student_order
Details at logfile: /home/srv-hadoop/pig_1500995099397.log
2017-07-25 17:05:07,648 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 8 seconds and 442 milliseconds (8442 ms)
```

I get :

```
Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1897657638_0001    ->  null,
null    ->  null,
null
```

Bit, if I execute : **pig -x local data.pig** --> it works fine

I missed something ?

Comment: Check the path of the file.What is the delimiter used in the data.txt between the fields?

Comment: Filepath is good and fields are separated by coma. I updated my question with data.txt file. I have to put data.txt to datanode directory and data.pig in namenode ?

Answer (score 1):

Hey It seems that your 'data.txt' is on your local file system. When you run 'pig -x mapreduce' it expect input to be in hdfs.

Since  '/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt' file is on local file system your 'pig -x local ' is working.

make directory on hadoop filesystem:

1. hadoop fs -mkdir -p /home/srv-hadoop/

copy your data.txt file from local to hadoop

2. hadoop fs -put /home/srv-hadoop/data.txt /home/srv-hadoop/

now run you pig in mapreduce mode. It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You have 6 fields in your file and the schema that you have specified has only 5 fields.You have another field after lastname,age perhaps.Modify your load statement like below.

```
student = LOAD '/home/srv-hadoop/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',')   as (id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray,age:int, phone:chararray, city:chararray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: pig -x mapreduce file://data.pig